# Hard edges on sculpted mesh

Tags: normals

I'm sure someone else has asked this question but I'm not sure exactly what to search for.

I am trying to sculpt a tin-box kind of thing with smooth beveled edges around the corners. When I go into sculpting and try to add a simple raised part around one of the corners, I end up with these hard-looking verticle edges, I could go around the smooth out all of these manually, but I'm sure there is a simpler solution.

Also, in the image, you can see that when I bake a normal map of this, those hard lines appear on the normal map and look terrible on my low-poly model. Does anyone know how to sculpt around an edge without getting these artifacts?[image]

Comment: I think you are going to need to upload the file so people can better understand what is going on in your scene. For a box like that why not just use sub-D modelling instead of sculpting?